# Ist "anderthalb" Plural oder Singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers

Die Frage ist einfach: Behandelt man "anderthalb" als Mehrzahl oder nicht? Ich glaube ja, aber selbstverständlich ist es mir nicht, denn die Frage ist: Fängt die Mehrzahl bei zwei an oder schon früher?

> Vor anderthalb Jahren war ich in Nordkorea.

oder

> Vor anderthalb Jahr war ich in Nordkorea.

#

> Anderthalb Dutzend Enten sind doch recht viel.

oder

> Anderthalb Dutzend Enten ist doch recht viel.

Wird die Sache anders, wenn man statt "anderthalb" "ein und ein halb" wählt? Wie ist es mit "eins Komma eins"?

> Ich habe eins Komma eins Hektar Wald geerbt.
>   oder
>   Ich habe eins Komma eins Hektare Wald geerbt.

Comment: Alles **Abzählbare**, was nicht mit *einer/eine/eines* beschrieben wird, steht im Plural. *Einskommanull Ente**n***. ABER: *einskommanull Hektar*. Weil Hektar nicht abzählbar sind.

Comment: Für 0,5 übrigens nicht anders als für 1,5 oder 2,5.

Comment: *Fängt die Mehrzahl bei zwei an oder schon früher?*
0 braucht auch Mehrzahl, -2 auch.

Comment: @Janka: Der Hektar ist nur eine Einheit (Dutzend m. E. auch), und steht daher im Singular (Ausnahmen: Zeiteinheiten und Einzelfälle wie Tonne). Das Abzählbare an sich sind ja die Eier oder Enten (Plural) bzw. Nicht-Abzählbare der Wald (Singular).

Comment: Nette Frage - Es ist natürlich Pluringular. Eins ist Singular, das Halbe mehr ein bißchen Plural ;). Aber nicht besonders spezifisch deutsch.

Comment: @Raketenolli Waelder sind durchaus abzaehlbar, ich kann ja auch zwei Waelder erben (einen hier, einen 100km entfernt). Interessant ist, dass Waelder darueber hinaus noch eine messbare Groesse haben, die sie aehnlich wie nicht abzaehlbare Objekte erscheinen lassen. Ein weiteres Beispiel hierfuer ware zB Stein. Ich kann 5 Steine haben (abzaehlbar), oder auch 5 Tonnen Stein ("scheinbar" nicht abzaehlbar).

Comment: @DirkLiebhold Natürlich. Interessant wird es aber, wenn man "5 Tonnen Stein" oder "5 Tonnen Steine" sagt. Auch wenn es eigentlich dasselbe bedeutet, stelle ich mir bei "5 Tonnen Stein" eher eine undefinierte Masse an Stein/Steinen vor, bei "5 Tonnen Steine" eben eine große Ansammlung eindeutig unterscheidbarer einzelner Steine,die zusammen 5 Tonnen wiegen. Noch anschaulicher ist der Unterschied m. E. bei "5 Tonnen Eier" (hat ein Lkw geladen) und "5 Tonnen Ei" (liegen nach einem Unfall auf der Straße verteilt, Riesensauerei).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Fängt die Mehrzahl bei zwei an oder schon früher?

Die Antwort: Es ist viel komplizierter.

Bei Kommazahlen wird meines Wissens immer die Mehrzahl verwendet:

> Dieser Vorgang dauert exakt eine Sekund**e**.
>
> Dieser Vorgang dauert 1,0 Sekund**en**.

... obwohl hier in beiden Fällen die Zahl 1 ist.

Bei Brüchen kommt es meines Wissens immer auf den Zähler an:

> Der andere Vorgang dauert **eine** halbe Sekund**e**.
>
> Der andere Vorgang dauert **fünf** zehntel Sekund**en**.

... obwohl auch hier die Zahl in beiden Fällen 1/2 ist.

> Behandelt man "anderthalb" als Mehrzahl oder nicht?

Gemischtrationale Zahlen (also Angabe eines Bruches durch Ganzzahl und Bruch) werden meines Wissens immer als Mehrzahl behandelt. Somit steht "anderthalb" in der Mehrzahl.

---

**Nachtrag**

> Ich habe eins Komma eins Hektare Wald geerbt.

Im Prinzip gilt das auch hier:

> Ich habe **eine** Quadratmeil**e** Land geerbt.
>
> Ich habe 1,0 Quadratmeil**en** Land geerbt.

Mit wenigen Ausnahmen (mir fallen außer Zeiteinheiten nur "Meile" und einige historische Einheiten ein) ist der Plural von Einheiten jedoch meistens identisch mit dem Singular:

> acht Kilogramm (und nicht: Kilogramm**e**)
>
> fünf Hektar (und nicht: Hektar**e**)
>
> drei Fuß (und nicht: Füße)

Trotzdem handelt es sich dabei um Singular und Plural:

> **Ein** Kilometer **ist** zu weit.
>
> **Zwei** Kilometer **sind** zu weit.

Comment: Du hast mir die Augen geöffnet

Answer (score 1):

Aus der [Etymologie von **anderthalb**](https://www.dwds.de/wb/anderthalb)

> **anderthalb**  *Adj.*   ‘einundeinhalb’, eigentl. ‘das andere (zweite) halb’

erkennt man, dass es sich hier um 2 zählbare Einheiten (ein Ganzes und ein Halbes) handelt. Also muss es im Plural stehen.

Answer (score -3):

Grimm schreibt: `seiner natur nach steht dies halb immer im sg.'

> ANDERTHALB, sesquialter, einundeinhalb. wie man dritthalb 2, vierthalb 3, fünfthalb 4 u. s. w. mit der ordinalzahl bildet, ist auch anderhalb vollkommen richtig, und die meinung, dasz der zählende auf die mitte oder hälfte von 1 zu 2 gelange, das andere (zweite) halb erreicht sei; auch heiszt es mhd. anderhalp (Ben. 1, 614b). als sich allmälich das gefühl für die ordinalität des wortes ander schwächte, begann man t von vierthalb, fünfthalb nachzuahmen und, gleich als gelte anderte für ander, anderthalb zu schreiben, wie nun allgemein üblich geworden ist. anderthalb ellen. 2 Mos. 25, 10, 17. 23; anderthalb pfund, anderthalb meilen; mein vatter hett nur einen arm, so hab ich anderthalben. Fischart Garg. 94b; seiner natur nach steht dies halb immer im sg.

http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB

Comment: Also sagt man "Vor 1,5 Jahr war ich in Korea"? Link zu Grimm wäre wünschenswert.